# removing 1px "frameborder" from the fracebook iFrame (app)

Tags: facebook, iframe, border, facebook-iframe

So, facebooks somehow adds a 1px border to your appplication when using an iFrame.

Is there any way to get remove this?

I checked the source code, and it has frameborder="0"

My .php also contains:

```
html, body, iframe, div {
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        }
```

what to do?

(or do I just have to live with only having 748 px?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was because I was using some old setting for embedding my app.  This setting is no longer available, so this is of no use anymore!

Answer (score 0):

anyway, the facebook frame code has a bug, it should use frameBorder="0" instead of frameborder (note the capital B, needed for it to work in ie7 and below)